# Python: got an AttributeError when using the font attribue of the openpyxl module

Tags: python, openpyxl

The code below is from a Python tutoring website. But I get the AttributeError when running it.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import Font
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet')
italic24Font = Font(size=24, italic=True)
sheet['A1'].font = italic24Font
sheet['A1'] = 'Hello world!'
wb.save('styled.xlsx')
```

Error message:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\zs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\test.py", line 6, in <module>
    sheet['A1'].font = italic24Font
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Comment: You should include the full traceback and the version of openpyxl you're using because it looks like the site you're looking at is out of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try as below,

```
your_cell.font.size = 24
your_cell.font.italic = True
```

and also check the [doc](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html#applying-styles) for clear understanding on how to apply styles.

Answer (score -1):

I hava the same errors too:

```
c.fill = PatternFill('solid', fgColor=RED, bgColor=RED, fill_type='darkGray')
```

change it:

```
c.fill.bgColor = RED
```

But nothing changed, there is a error too.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31628102)